# I want a cell to reflect how many vacation hours you get depending on how many years of service

Tags: excel

```
CELL A1
1/3/2006

CELL J1
=YEAR(TODAY())


CELL B1
```

I want a formula that states if Cell A1 is less than 3 years from CellJ1 input "75", if equal or more than 3 years but less than 10 years input "112", if equal or more than 10 years input 150.

Comment: Do you want to round to the nearest year, or go by days or months?

Comment: @Tim by day
ugh this min requirement rule is annoying on this site - can't post a quick yes no , whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this in B1,

```
=150-(EDATE(A1, 36)>TODAY())*37-(EDATE(A1, 120)>TODAY())*38
```

Comment: Well it does work but I can't decipher at all how your forumla does it. - thank you!

Comment: ahh i figured out what you did, pretty smooth, you took the higher number 150 and came up with checks to change it by subtracting from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIF function here to determine the number of years service, and nest that within a LOOKUP function to return the correct number, e.g.

> =LOOKUP(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"y"),{0,3,10;75,112,150})