# Is there a way to use a drop down in A1 cell to stipulate which formula to use in A2 Cell

Tags: excel, nested

Assuming thats the best way to go about what I want to do...
these are the 2 forumlas I want to be able to toggle between:

```
=150-(EDATE(F2, 37)>TODAY())*37.5-(EDATE(F2, 120)>TODAY())*37.5

=80-(EDATE(F2, 37)>TODAY())*20-(EDATE(F2, 120)>TODAY())*20
```

for a better idea of what I'm trying to do here's a screenshot:

[image: CellB1]

is a drop down (FUll Time, Part Time) made with Data Validation.
Depending which I choose I want Cell C1 to reflect the proper forumla...
The formula by the way looks at the CellA1 and depending on how many years of service will show how many vacation days shows in cell

Comment: `=IF(condition, formula #1, formula #2)`?

Comment: @MarcB
That looks promising Marc but I'm afraid I only got this far with the help of folks like you who helped me come up with the formulas above....I would need to know the correct syntax for the condition

Comment: The condition would be where you test the contents of B2

Comment: @pnuts
The end results of the formulas is a number that represents how many vaction days a person has if they started 10 yrs ago, or 3 yrs ago or less- so thats why that year tag is there...

Comment: Does this site allow you to upload the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't the two formulas doing the same thing except the part time version returns 8/15 of the value of the full time? In which case you can  use just one formula and then multiply by 8/15 if G2 = "part Time", e.g.

`=IF(G2="part time",8/15,1)*(150-(EDATE(F2, 37)>TODAY())*37.5-(EDATE(F2, 120)>TODAY())*37.5)`

Personally though, I would use `DATEDIF` as I suggested in your original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403622/i-want-a-cell-to-reflect-how-many-vacation-hours-you-get-depending-on-how-many-y/29407466#29407466) - that would be even easier to adjust:

Then that would look something like this:

`=(MATCH(DATEDIF(F2,TODAY(),"y"),{0,3,10})+1)*IF(G2="part time",20,37.5)`

although I notice you changed the 36 in `EDATE` (representing 3 years) to 37 in **Jeeped**'s suggested formula - is that deliberate?

Comment: Sweet - that is perfect!!! - 
=(MATCH(DATEDIF(F2,TODAY(),"y"),{0,3,10})+1)*IF(G2="part time",20,37.5)

Answer (score 0):

If the user is unable to enter anything else into B2, you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(B2="Full Time", *FullTimeFormula*, *PartTimeFormula*)
```

If the user may enter their own data, you may want to use the following formula:

```
=IF(B2="Full Time", *FullTimeFormula*, IF(B2="Part Time",*PartTimeFormula*,"[Error message here]"))
```

Comment: @its not working for me, i'll keep playing with it and look everything over but doesn't seem to work..... This is what i'm pasting: =IF(G2="Full Time", *=150-(EDATE(F2, 37)>TODAY())*37.5-(EDATE(F2, 120)>TODAY())*37.5, *=80-(EDATE(F2, 37)>TODAY())*20-(EDATE(F2, 120)>TODAY())*20)
am i suppose to leave the "="symbol i tried it without it still doesn't work:
=IF(G2="Full Time", *150-(EDATE(F2, 37)>TODAY())*37.5-(EDATE(F2, 120)>TODAY())*37.5, *80-(EDATE(F2, 37)>TODAY())*20-(EDATE(F2, 120)>TODAY())*20)

Comment: @pnuts I always just say A1 and A2 for ease of communication, try to keep things simple. The cells in my formula are actually the true locations.  My formulas are still working individually but they do not work when combined

Comment: Yes you don't need the = signs but you also need to get rid of the * at the start of each - but I've also posted an alternative answer if you care to look

Answer (score 0):

Final Answer:

```
=If(B2="Full Time",150-(EDATE(F2, 37)>TODAY())*37.5-(EDATE(F2, 120)>TODAY())*37.5,If(B2="Part Time",80-(EDATE(F2, 37)>TODAY())*20-(EDATE(F2, 120)>TODAY())*20,0),0)
```